# how to fetch data from multiple json for creating a barchart using D3.js

Tags: d3.js

i am new to using D3.js. i have two seperate jsons. from one json i want to pick one value and show it on X-axis. from second json i want to pick some value and show it on y axis. i have one common thing in both the json that is objectID. but not getting how to fetch these values and show on barchart. i have shared both my JSONs at below URLs.

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=1198d736c68ea9be81e77c7fe3982ab3
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=0dba90821a577ab28b5725b877706f3d

Comment: why -1? what is wrong with this question i could not understand. please help me in understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to request both files and then manually merge the data.  To request both files, I'd use [d3.queue](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue), and merge the data with simple `forEach` loops:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, 'json1.json')
    .defer(d3.json, 'json2.json')
    .await(makePlot);

function makePlot(error, json1, json2){
  if (error) throw error;

  var merge = [];
  json1.forEach(function(d0){
    json2.forEach(function(d1){
      // for matching ids, create a datapoint
      if (d0.ObjectID === d1.ObjectID){
        merge.push(
          {
            ObjectID: d0.ObjectID,
            x: d1.Name,
            y: d0.Defects.Count
          }
        );
      }
    });
  });
```

---

[Here's some full running code.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ufskW6IV9vATOEwtGZxu?p=preview)